# Helix Swarm - Syntax error in 'swarm.job'

Tags: perforce

I am trying to set up swarm-triggers on a Helix Core 2017.1 server for a Helix Swarm 2018.2 server (both in separate docker containers orchestrated using docker-compose) but am getting the above error when I try to pipe the results of `swarm-trigger.pl -o` to `p4 triggers -i`:

```
# both with and without config file -c fails
/root/swarm-trigger.pl -c /root/swarm-trigger.conf -o > /root/generated_triggers.txt
# Tried both with and without the %quote% parts, stripped out using sed.
#sed -i -e 's/%quote//g' -e 's/%%/%/g' /root/generated_triggers.txt         
sed '/^\s*#/d' -i /root/generated_triggers.txt                                                                   
cat /root/generated_triggers.txt | p4 triggers -i
```

My original piped commands also fail with the same error:

```
/root/swarm-trigger.pl -c /root/swarm-trigger.conf -o | sed -e 's/%quote//g' -e 's/%%/%/g' | sed '/^\s*#/d' | p4 triggers -i
/root/swarm-trigger.pl -c /root/swarm-trigger.conf -o | sed '/^\s*#/d' | p4 triggers -i
```

So `docker-compose` error log:

```
perforce    | + sed '/^\s*#/d'
perforce    | + /root/swarm-trigger.pl -c /root/swarm-trigger.conf -o
perforce    | + p4 triggers -i
perforce    | Error in triggers specification.
perforce    | Error detected at line 1.
perforce    | Syntax error in 'swarm.job'.
perforce    | /run.sh exited 1
```

Here's the file that `p4 triggers -i` fails on:

```
[root@9877302137d8 /]# cat /root/generated_triggers.txt 
swarm.job        form-commit    job    "%quote%/root/swarm-trigger.pl%quote% -c %quote%/root/swarm-trigger.conf%quote% -t job           -v %formname%"
swarm.user       form-commit    user   "%quote%/root/swarm-trigger.pl%quote% -c %quote%/root/swarm-trigger.conf%quote% -t user          -v %formname%"
swarm.userdel    form-delete    user   "%quote%/root/swarm-trigger.pl%quote% -c %quote%/root/swarm-trigger.conf%quote% -t userdel       -v %formname%"
swarm.group      form-commit    group  "%quote%/root/swarm-trigger.pl%quote% -c %quote%/root/swarm-trigger.conf%quote% -t group         -v %formname%"
swarm.groupdel   form-delete    group  "%quote%/root/swarm-trigger.pl%quote% -c %quote%/root/swarm-trigger.conf%quote% -t groupdel      -v %formname%"
swarm.changesave form-save      change "%quote%/root/swarm-trigger.pl%quote% -c %quote%/root/swarm-trigger.conf%quote% -t changesave    -v %formname%"
swarm.shelve     shelve-commit  //...  "%quote%/root/swarm-trigger.pl%quote% -c %quote%/root/swarm-trigger.conf%quote% -t shelve        -v %change%"
swarm.commit     change-commit  //...  "%quote%/root/swarm-trigger.pl%quote% -c %quote%/root/swarm-trigger.conf%quote% -t commit        -v %change%"
swarm.shelvedel  shelve-delete  //...  "%quote%/root/swarm-trigger.pl%quote% -c %quote%/root/swarm-trigger.conf%quote% -t shelvedel     -v %change% -w %client% -u %user% -d %quote%%clientcwd%%quote% -a %quote%%argsQuoted%%quote% -s %quote%%serverVersion%%quote%"
```

I compared this to the results from our production Helix Core server and the only difference I can see is that I did not put my swarm-trigger.pl into a depot. However, in your instructions, this is not problematic (see [step 6b](https://www.perforce.com/manuals/swarm/Content/Swarm/setup.perforce.html))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I didn't prepend the contents being streamed to `p4 triggers -i` with a line containing only `Triggers:`, like so:

```
/root/swarm-trigger.pl -c /root/swarm-trigger.conf -o | sed '/^\s*#/d' | awk '{print "Triggers:" $0;}' | p4 triggers -i
```

It is not possible to simply append to the Perforce triggers, and so one must do something like so:

```
p4 triggers -o > tmp
/root/swarm-trigger.pl -c /root/swarm-trigger.conf -o | sed '/^\s*#/d' >> tmp
p4 triggers -i < tmp
```